# Why didn't Nebula warn them about Thanos?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers Endgame*, after reaching Morag in 2014, Nebula and Rhodes have this conversation:

> **Nebula**: We're not the only ones in 2014 looking for the stones.
>   **Rhodes**: Wait, what? Who else is looking for the stones?
>   **Nebula**: My father, my sister and me.

All other stones that they target to get is free of Thanos' direct involvement. In 2014, Thanos is only looking for the Power Stone. The equivalent of going to Morag in 2014 to get the Power Stone is going to Vormir in 2018 to the Soul Stone.

> **Gamora**: Father has found an Infinity Stone. On a planet called Morag.

Thanos finds the location of the stone first. He is in the vicinity of Morag. Only after that does he find out about the 2023 Nebula on Morag. Nebula remembers looking for the stone in 2014 in Morag. In the original timeline Quill gets to it before them. Which is fine. But Nebula already knows of the threat that Thanos was looking for the stone in Morag in 2014. So going there even 6 months earlier would have been safer.

Well, if Nebula knew from her own past of the the threat of getting to Morag in **2014**, because she, along with her sister and Thanos were in the vicinity of Morag looking for the power stone then.

**QUESTION**: Why didn't she warn the team about the fact that Thanos was in the vicinity of Morag in 2014?

If she had, they might have gone there maybe a little earlier, when Thanos wasn't there. No one knew about Thanos but Nebula, why didn't she warn everyone about the obvious risk of running into Thanos in 2014 in Morag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there was high risk of running into Thanos. Thanos himself did not go to Morag to retrieve the orb. He made an agreement that Ronan will retrieve the orb, who in turn ordered his subordinate Korath to actually do it.

They (the Avengers) went for the stone at that time because they know for a fact that the stone will be there at that moment when Quill found it. What if they traveled there some time earlier and the stone was not there?

Comment: In addition they knew that Quill would get there at this exact moment and followed him, because they didn't exactly know where the stone was and how you could get it.

Comment: @SethFrkinRollins I thought that as well at first, but not so sure now. Korath appeared at the exact location of the stone. If he knew the location, I suppose Ronan knew as well. And since Nebula was working with him at that moment, I think there's a decent chance she knew too

Comment: James Gunn told in a commentary (don't have the link but a Wiki referenced it somehow) that the sea level loweres and the temple is accessible. So they had to retrieve the orb at that time because otherwise they couldn't reach it

Comment: @Clayn Interesting, never heard of it. Still, it seems unlikely that just by being underwater it will keep people from trying to retrieve it, no matter how dangerous it could be. Come on, it's one of the most powerful objects in the universe

Comment: @ArthurShveida It seems that the temple was build to protect the orb by an advanced civilization but due to "warming" the planet wsa flooded. So i guess it's a mix between not knowing where the orb is at all and than finding it on the planet. (https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Morag) found the information here but the commentary seems to be only audio. However i only rely on the information around the movie but not any comic

Comment: @ArthurShveida In addition, they had a limited supply of Pym particles, what if they reached earlier and didn't find the stone. It was too much risk to carry.